# How do i unstage/revert unapplied migrations?

Tags: python, django, git, django-migrations

I would like to unstage (analogus to git) all the unapplied migrations. `showmigrations` gives :

```
blog
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_auto_20180509_1033
[ ] 0003_auto_20180531_1951
[ ] 0004_auto_20180531_2039
[ ] 0005_post_tags
```

I have 3 unapplied migrations. I assume they don't have any effect on my database tables right now? (because they are not applied, please correct me if i am wrong). I have read other answers and didn't find an easy way to just unstage all the unapplied migrations (for example : `git reset` command ). Docs talk about `makemigrations` being analogous to `git add` and `migrate` being analogous to `git commit`.

( I also didn't get how i have 3 unapplied migrations, isn't all unapplied migrations should be in a single file? Like till you don't commit, you are just staging the changes, so everything should be in a single file? In such scenario, when i use `migrate` command, will all the migrations be applied? )

Comment: all you need is remove the files from disk, and do new `makemigrations`.

Comment: If it's not applied, just delete it and makemigrations again